# Error running Cucumber Geb tests in IntelliJ IDE using groovy

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, junit4, geb, cucumber-jvm

I am getting following error when running Geb tests in IntelliJ IDE.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: features.step_definitions.MyHomeStepDef.to() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class geb.pages.MyLandingPage]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), with(groovy.lang.Closure)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:904)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
  at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.invoke(GroovyBackend.java:133)
  at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyStepDefinition.execute(GroovyStepDefinition.java:48)
  at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:45)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:248)
  ...
  at cucumber.cli.Main.main(Main.java:12)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
  at ✽.Given I am on the My home page(D:\MyFolder\src\test\resources\features\my-login-page.feature:5)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: features.step_definitions.MyHomeStepDef.to() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class geb.pages.MyLandingPage]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), with(groovy.lang.Closure)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
  at features.step_definitions.MyHomeStepDef$_run_closure1.doCall(MyHomeStepDef.groovy:25)
  .....
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Error occurred in the step definition file when try to access the web page via Geb

```
Given(~'^I am on the My home page$') { ->

    to MyLandingPage
    waitFor { at(MyLandingPage) }
}
```

Tests are running perfectly in command-line with `gradle test` command

Comment: This may sound obvious, but make sure you have added the directory where your geb scripts reside as a 'test source' directory.  So if Geb stuff is in src/groovy, right-click and select 'Mark Directory As' > 'Test Sources Root'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally found a solution. Based on the sample project https://github.com/geb/geb-example-cucumber-jvm.git you need to make sure the file 'env.groovy' is also referenced in the glue list in the run configuration.
[image: cucumber-java settings]
Then the BindingUpdater is loaded correctly and all the geb specific methods are available in the steps file when running the tests.

Comment: is there a way to avoid configuring intellij every time for each feature?

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding Browser.drive closure fixed the problem.
So your example would be:

```
Given(~'^I am on the My home page$') { ->
    Browser.drive {
        to MyLandingPage
        waitFor { at(MyLandingPage) }
    }
}
```